# Compoud operator (+=) and && in C, weird value

Tags: c, output, compound-assignment

Looking at this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
  int a = -1;
  int b = 0xfc; // = 252
  b+=a && a++;
  printf("%d %d\n", a, b);
}
```

the output I think should be is:

```
0 251
```

Actually, the real output is:

```
0 253
```

But why? associativity of && is from left to right, so

1. b = b - 1(a)  (and b should be 251)
2. the left part is true so: a++ (a = 0)

There's something wrong with my hypothesis, can someone explain to me what?

If can help that the output of gdb (with watchpoints to a and b):

```
Old value = 0
New value = -1
main () at test.c:7
7         int b = 0xfc;
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Hardware watchpoint 2: b

Old value = 0
New value = 252
main () at test.c:8
8         b+=a && a++;
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Hardware watchpoint 3: a

Old value = -1
New value = 0
0x0000555555555172 in main () at test.c:8
8         b+=a && a++;
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Hardware watchpoint 2: b

Old value = 252
New value = 253
main () at test.c:9
9         printf("%d %d\n", a, b);
```

Comment: Why would you waste time on operator precedence and would you not just write clear code that can only be interpreted one way?

Comment: `&&` has higher precedence than `+=`.

Comment: *`but in C a && whatever is equal to 1`* - no - it is equal `1` or `0` depending on  `a` & `whatever`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The explanation is very simple.

`a && a++` is a logical operation and its result can be `0` or `1`. As `a` is non zero and any non zero value is considered as the `true` the result of this operation is `1`.

This value is added to `252`. The result displayed is `253`.

Comment: so is like `b+= (a && a++);`, and because `a && a++` is 1, so 1 is added, right?